# How to send notification from one mobile to other mobile in android

Tags: android, facebook

How to send notification from one mobileApp to other mobile, notification can be of anytype, for eg. say one friend is sending game challange. I have seen facebook challange tutorial for android, but i am getting notification on my android Facebook browser instead I want it to come on app directly.

Comment: what do you mean by facebook android browser, is it facebook running on android browser ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google cloud messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html).

Comment: I am working on google cloud messaging and project is working fine from web to android messaging but now want to tht can is send message to multiple clients by web page http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: In GCM i have seen tutorial about sending push notification from server to mobile, but i want do this through mobile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Cloud Messaging have look at 
[Implementing GCM Client](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html) and [Implementing GCM Server](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html)

Before that you need to enable GCM for you application package that you can do [here using Google Console](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=devconsole&passive=1209600&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fapis%2Fconsole%2F&followup=https%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fapis%2Fconsole%2F)

from here you will have to enable GCM feature for your application after accepting T&C you will have app_key and sender Id 
sender id you should put on you client and app_key will be on server side.
you can also find simple Client project in API-DEMOS and server side is also available in API-DEMOS

Comment: I have implemented GCM, but in that i can send notification from web to mobile but instead i want it to send it through mobile app.